# how to eval a string within a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

this works in PHP:

```
 $i = 4;
 $fruit4 = 'apple';
 $answer = $fruit{$i};
 echo $answer;  // apple
```

so i hoped this would work in javascript:

```
var i = 4;
var fruit4 = 'apple';
var answer = fruit{i};
print(answer);
```

but no luck! is there a way to do this using javascript?

NOTE: i realize this is more easily done with an array (var fruit[4] = 'apple') but that isn't an option this time due to pre-existing constraints.

thanks in advance!

Comment: *Thankfully* it's not possible to do in js (in a general case)

Comment: thanks for weighing in, but why should we be grateful for that if it isn't helpful?

Comment: Because it allows you to make terrible code even more terrible too easily.

Comment: why is it terrible? when you're working with pre-defined numbered variables (with an unpredictable pattern) and can't use an array, what choice does one have?

Comment: i think you misunderstood me. when i say "pre-existing constraints" i mean "not of my own making." i'm working with a client's dataset in which fields are named something like var1, var2, var3, etc. if it were up to me, i'd certainly use an array, and i wouldn't be here asking for help. why even answer if you can't contribute? no need to answer that. just think on it.

Comment: "client's dataset in which fields are named" --- what is a "field" here? How it comes to a variable with the same name? PS: I was not trolling and I'm not trolling now. Seriously - what is it and how it gets into JS runtime with those terrible names?

Comment: javascript queries a database (via ajax) to load a json object that looks something like this: { "var1": "apple", "var2": "banana", "var3": "orange" } and then parses that object into the variables i have to work with. the number of variables in each json object varies, which is what i meant by "unpredictable pattern," which makes it hard to translate into an array client-side. the eval solution was exactly what i needed and solves the mess elegantly. sorry for calling you a troll. :)

Comment: if it's an object - you don't need it at all. Just use `for-in` to iterate over object's keys. So, uhm, you've just asked a wrong question presumably. Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/145588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has an function called eval, so try to use it.
For example

```
var answer = eval("fruit"+ i);
```

Comment: perfect! thanks, hayk. i probably should have thought of this, having used the word "eval" in my question's title! _thankfully_ @zerkms was mistaken and/or just trolling.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a way of accessing properties via square bracket notation so that you can use strings and variables to get to them.

For example, if your `fruit4` (From the code in your post) is in the global scope in the browser:

```
var answer = window['fruit' + i];
```

Comment: What if it's not in a global scope? What if it runs not in a browser?

Comment: If it's not global, use appropriate scope. I said "for example". I mean, _honestly_. :/

Comment: This answer's a bit esoteric, but much better than using `eval` imo.

Answer (score 0):

```
eval('var answer = fruit' + i);
```